# Spring MVC, deserialize single JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

How can I easily separate JSON values that are sent in the same request?

Given that I POST a JSON to my server:

```
{"first":"A","second":"B"}
```

If I implement the following method in the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void handleRequest(@RequestBody String input) { 
    // ...
}
```

then the `input` parameter will constitute a String with the entire JSON object, `{"first":"A","second":"B"}`. What I really want is two separate Strings (or a String and an int whichever is suitable for the particular request) with just the two values (other key / value pairs that the client may send should be ignored).

If the strings were sent as request parameters instead of JSON request body it would be simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleRequest(@RequestParam("first") String first, 
                          @RequestParam("second") String second) { 
    // ...
}
```

I know that I can create a simple bean class that can be used in conjunction with the `@RequestBody` annotation that will contain both `A` and `B` when used, but it seems like a detour, since they will have different purposes inside the web app.

Dependencies:
org.springframework : spring-web : 3.1.0.RELEASE
org.codehaus.jackson : jackson-mapper-asl : 1.9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### POJO

```
public class Input {
    private String first;
    private String second;

    //getters/setters
}
```

...and then:

```
public void handleRequest(@RequestBody Input input)
```

In this case you need [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to be available on the CLASSPATH.

### Map

```
public void handleRequest(@RequestBody Map<String, String> input)
```

Comment: The POJO corresponds to the bean class solution that I suggested (and that I should have written in the question). The Map may be a viable solution...

Comment: Instead of Map I would recommend using `JsonNode` as the intermediate type. Not a big deal, just bit more convenient, safe.

Comment: `JsonNode` looks interesting, especially if you need to convert the input to other types than Strings, or if the JSON structure is more complex than a one level key/value map.

Comment: What if you have two subtype classes that extend a supertype? i assume you cant put the parent class in the requestmapping method parameter?

Answer (score 3):

I have written a custom [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) that does exactly this, combined with a custom annotation.

I don't have the source available to me now, but basically I annotated my method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleRequest(@JsonField("first") String first, @JsonField("second") String second) { 
    // ...
}
```

Then my `JsonFieldWebArgumentResolver` checks if the method parameter is annotated with `JsonField`, and if it is it extracts the actual type from the parameter (not quite straight-forward it turns out if you want to handle generic parameters as well, such as `List<String>` or `List<Pojo>`), and invokes Jackson's JsonParser manually to create the correct type. It's a shame I can't show you any code, but that's the gist of it.

**However**, that solution is for **Spring MVC 3.0**, and if you are using **3.1** I think you will be better off using a custom [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) instead. But the idea should be the same.

Comment: Elegant. An annotation like your `@JsonField` would be the perfect fit for my problem. I especially like the idea of making it generic, but I have to read up on this subject and on the `JsonNode` API that @StaxMan commented on. However, the clients currently posts really simple key/value Strings, so I have a hard time motivating the additional cost. I'll definitely keep this suggestion in mind.